# Always 404 status code on AllowAnonymous action in dual authentication type asp.net core 2 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 project with two Areas, **Admin** and **Api**. The first one (Admin) is secured with cookies, the second one with JWT. This was created following this tutorial: https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2 and everything works as expected. Validation with cookies works great, routing works great and the api identifies users correctly when bearer token is sent.

**Admin** area uses `[Authorize]` attribute while **Api** uses `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

The problem arises when trying to call `POST: /Api/Auth/GetToken` from postman (https://www.getpostman.com/), even when code reaches a `return BadRequest();` or `return Unauthorized();` the final status code is always 404, except when credentials are valid and `return Ok();` is called. This action is under a controller with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` but the action has the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. When I call this action from postman with  no bearer token I can debug code, so it is still working as expected up to here, but the return status code obtained in postman is not the expected one.

For me, it looks like the problem is all about the redirect ocurring when an error ocurs, maybe `OnLoginRedirect` event, but this is an Anonymous action and I am returning certain status codes. What could be the problem here?

Action code in AuthController:

```
public class AuthController : ApiBaseController
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _config;

        public AuthController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IConfigurationRoot config)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _config = config;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken([FromBody] LoginDto dto)
        {
            if (dto == null) return BadRequest();
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(dto.Email);

            if (user == null) return Unauthorized();

            var result = _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, dto.Password, false);

            if (!result.Result.Succeeded) return Unauthorized();

            return Ok(GetTokensInfo(user));
        }`
```

ApiBaseController code:

```
[Area("Api")]
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public abstract class ApiBaseController : Controller
{ }`
```

**UPDATE:** The 404 occurs only on `[HttpPost]` actions. When `[HttpGet]` attribute is specified all works as expected.

**UPDATE #2:** When commenting this line: `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");`  at Configure Method of Startup.cs  everything works ok.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code. If you remove `[AllowAnonymous]` is the behavior different?

Comment: Just tried that and I still get 404, but this time, breakpoint inside the action is not reached. Which tells me a bit more. But still no solution.

Comment: Are you sure you have a route that handles `/error/{0}`?

Comment: There was actually a middleware that was handling that. With the code modified in the Startup.cs as posted in my answere the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to the root of the problem as posted in Update #2. The final solution I'm taking for now is modifying the Configure method at the Startup.cs file with the following code:

```
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
        });
```